# Dados truncados para a coluna vlrDesconto Laravel

Tags: laravel

Estou tentando salvar campo com formatação pelo `jqueryMaskMoney`, porem esta dando **erro dados truncados**

```
 $("#desconto01").maskMoney({thousands: ".", decimal: ","});
```

Erro:

> [image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

CONTROLLER

```
 public function store(Request $request){

  // try{
  //   DB::beginTransaction();
    $dados = new MapaCompra;
    $mytime = Carbon::now('America/Sao_Paulo');
    $dados->data=$mytime->toDateTimeString(); 
    $dados->infadicionais=$request->get('infadicionais');             
    $dados->orc01=$request->get('orc01');             
    $dados->orc02=$request->get('orc02');             
    $dados->orc03=$request->get('orc03');             
    $dados->codpg01=$request->get('codpg01');             
    $dados->codpg02=$request->get('codpg02');             
    $dados->codpg03=$request->get('codpg03');             
    $dados->obs01=$request->get('obs01');             
    $dados->obs02=$request->get('obs02');             
    $dados->obs03=$request->get('obs03');             
    $dados->desconto01=$request->get('desconto01');             
    $dados->desconto02=$request->get('desconto02');             
    $dados->desconto03=$request->get('desconto03');             
    $dados->idforn01=$request->get('idforn01');             
    $dados->idforn02=$request->get('idforn02');             
    $dados->idforn03=$request->get('idforn03');             
    $dados->acrescimo01=$request->get('acrescimo01');             
    $dados->acrescimo02=$request->get('acrescimo02');             
    $dados->acrescimo03=$request->get('acrescimo03');             
    $dados->status='AA';
    $dados->data_status=$mytime->toDateTimeString(); 
    $dados->empresa_id=$request->session()->get('idempresa');     
    $dados->user_id=Auth::user()->id;   
    $dados->ativo='a';       
    $dados->save();

    // $idproduto=$request->get('idproduto');
    // $qnt=$request->get('qnt');
    // $detalhes=$request->get('detalhe');
    // $idcentrocusto=$request->get('idcentrocusto');        

    // $cont = 0;
    // while($cont < count($idproduto)){
    //   $detalhe = new SolicitacaoDet();
    //   $detalhe->idsolicitacao=$solicitacoes->idsolicitacao;
    //   $detalhe->idproduto=$idproduto[$cont];
    //   $detalhe->qnt=$qnt[$cont];
    //   $detalhe->detalhe=$detalhes[$cont];
    //   $detalhe->idcentrocusto=$idcentrocusto[$cont];         
    //   $detalhe->save();
    //   $cont=$cont+1;
    // }

  //   DB::commit();

  // }catch(\Exception $e){
  //   DB::rollback();
  // }

  return Redirect::to('compra/mapacompra');
```

MINHA TELA PARA COTAÇÕES
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Na hora de salvar esse dado ele precisa ser convertido por exemplo: `1.000,00` para `1000.00`. Isso é um exemplo, mas, como você não colocou a parte do código fica complicado dizer algo a mais, se puder coloque o código do `controller`

Comment: Obrigado pelo retorno. No meu controlle recebo ele assim  $dados->desconto01=$request->get('desconto01');

Comment: posta o código do controller man

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dados truncados, é porque, o valor passado é maior do que está configurado no banco de dados e também precisa converte o valor que está no formato brasileiro para o americano, *exemplo*:

```
$dados->desconto01 = 0;
$desconto01 = $request->get('desconto01');
$desconto01 = str_replace('.','',$desconto01);
$desconto01 = str_replace(',','.',$desconto01);
if (is_numeric($desconto01))
{
    $dados->desconto01 = $desconto01;
}
```

A grosso modo é assim, pode ser feito um `helper` ou função para automatizar, *exemplo* simples de uma função com valor padrão:

```
function number_decimal($valor, $default = 0)
{
    $valor = str_replace('.','',$valor);
    $valor = str_replace(',','.',$valor);
    if (is_numeric($valor))
    {
        return $valor;
    }
    return $default;
}
```

ai só chamar

```
$dados->desconto01 = number_decimal($request->get('desconto01'));
```

Comment: faço isso no controller ou melhor na view via javascript? O que me aconcelha?

Comment: eu faria o seguinte, uma função para converter isso no backend (controller). @frodrigues

Comment: Testei esse codigo no controller ainda deu o erro.

Comment: @frodrigues qual erro?

Comment: O mesmo erro Dados truncados para coluna desconto01.

Comment: Olha só, como está configurado essa base de dados? o campo desconto01 como você configurou? @frodrigues

Comment: Estou usando type = decimal(19,4)

Comment: o valor que você está passando nesse `$desconto01` é qual? exemplifique @frodrigues

Comment: Estou fazendo testes com valores dezenas (10,00), centenas(100,00) e milhares(1.000,00) e valores com centavos (10,50 ou 100,50 ou 1.050,50)

Comment: Virgilio funcionou sim   $desconto01 = $request->get('desconto01');
        $desconto01 = str_replace('.','',$desconto01);
  $desconto01 = str_replace(',','.',$desconto01);
       
        if (is_numeric($desconto01))
        {
          $dados->desconto01=$desconto01;
        }

Comment: corrigi um erro meu aqui de digitação. Agora como poderia ser essa função tenho varios dados para tratar e uma inserção muito grande

Comment: @frodrigues deixei um exemplo!

Comment: Show funciou blz. Obrigado;